# More than one "bad point" in a contour

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following complex function $z^2/(z^2+2)$ and the positively oriented contour $abs(z) = 4$. When I want to compute the contour integral, I know that both of the poles of the function are in the contour, hence I'm curious, do you sum up the individual integrals you obtain after finding the residues - and will that always give zero? I haven't been formally introduced to the Residue Theorem yet, but based on Cauchys's Integral Formula, I am led to believe that these two are intimately related somehow.

Comment: Are you asking how to compute this integral using residues? Or, since you mention that you haven't learned the residue theorem, are you simply looking for a way to compute it?

Comment: Computing this integral using residues. I get 0 as my answer when I sum the two integrals I get, but I'm wondering can we generalize this for any complex function that has more than one bad point in its domain?

Comment: @RobertIsrael This answers my question, thank you! You can post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) says that for a simple positively-oriented closed contour $C$, under appropriate conditions $\oint_C f(z)\; dz$ is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f$ at its singularities inside $C$.

No, in the case of two singularities the sum is not always $0$.  However, in the case of a rational function with denominator of degree at least $2$ more than the numerator, the sum of the residues at all the poles turns out to be $0$ (the condition on degrees is not necessary if you include a residue at $\infty$).